# How should I devise database schema for OAuth 1/2?

Tags: database, database-schema

Each provider implements oauth a little bit differently. For example, Instagram only gives back the accessToken and it doesn't have a refresh token nor does it have an expiration value returned like Google does. OAuth 1 requires you to store a resource owner secret and a resource owner token. In this situation, where they are conceptually the same thing, but they have very different values.

Different OAuths

Ex, Instagram

```
accessToken
```

Ex, Twitter

```
resourceOwnerKey
resourceOwnerSecret
```

Ex, Google

```
accessToken
expiresIn
refreshToken
```

Essentially these are all passwords, and how would I devise a schema with security in mind? I wouldn't salt these because I have to use them. I could encrypt/descrypt them, but that seems like unnecessary complexity.

One schema that I did have in mind was to do something like this, but querying them in a batch would be difficult (I imagine).

```
User model
has_many accessTokens

AccessToken model
schema
  user_id
  type enum: [ access_token, refresh_token, etc...]
  value string
```